# Angular material mdMenu onclose scrolls page to top in firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox, scroll, angular-material

I am having a simple angular material app having mdMenu at bottom of the page. On selecting an option, page scrolls to top.
This happens on firefox only (Tested on ver. 52.0.2).

Using angular ver. 1.6.4
Using angular-material ver 1.1.3

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/zcQvmjzXIqPtU5hjToPN)

```
<body>
<div style="height:1000px">This is top</div>
    <md-menu md-position-mode="target-right target">
        <md-button aria-label="Open demo menu" class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)">
            Menu
        </md-button>
        <md-menu-content width="2">
            <md-menu-item>
                <md-button>
                    <div>
                        <p flex>
                            Option </p>
                    </div>
                </md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
        </md-menu-content>
    </md-menu>
</body>
```

Comment: Fixed in angular-material ver 1.1.5.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug, at the time of posting this is still unresolved and has been backlogged by the devs on github.

Here is a link to the thread https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5690

There is a workaround proposed in the thread which is to use the following style :

```
body  {
height: auto;
}
```

While it does work for me, it causes vertical div jumping during the DOM load on my project which I do not appreciate.

Here are the two codepens that the user Magador posted to reproduce the bug
 (doesn't happen on Chrome, only firefox IE & edge)

Bug demo: http://codepen.io/Magador/pen/ZbmeRo

Demo resolved: http://codepen.io/Magador/pen/wKRBLg

Answer (score 0):

```
 angular.module('yourModule',[]).config( ['$anchorScrollProvider', 
        function($anchorScrollProvider) {
            $anchorScrollProvider.disableAutoScrolling();
        }]
    );
```

I resolved the problem by disabling the auto scroll. Be sure to clear the browser cache to ensure its working.